# Java: changing an already established array

Tags: arrays, java

So I am writing code that will change the elements of an array and print out ONLY the numbers that come after a certain target. In this case the target is the number 4.

meaning that if my original array contains the numbers 
5 6 4 3 2 1
the new array will only contain 3 2 1 because those are the numbers that come after the number 4.

I have this all in a method and so far my code prints out the number that comes after 4 but keeps printing that same number over and over and I don't know how to keep it printing the elements that follow

```
    boolean four;
    int location = 0;

    four = contains(newArray, 4);
    if (four == false) { // this returns the same array if there is no 4 
        return newArray;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
            if (newArray[i] == 4) {
               location = i;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < newArray.length; j++) {
            newArray[j] = newArray[location + 1];
        }
        return newArray;
    }
```

Comment: Second to last line:  Try changing location + 1.  [1,2,3,4,5,6]->[5,6,5,6,4,5,6] right?

Answer (score 1):

You could also make use of the native implementation of `System.arraycopy` like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 4) {
        location = i;
        break;
    }
}
int[] out = new int[arr.length-location-1];
System.arraycopy(arr, location+1, out, 0, arr.length-location-1);
return out;
```

Comment: Good mentioning arraycopy, performance is much better if i remember correctly

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new array, since you can't change an array's length :

```
   for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
       if(newArray[i] == 4) {
           location = i;
           break;
       }
   }  
   int [] arr = new int[newArray.length - location - 1];
   for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        arr[j] = newArray[location+1+j]; 
   }
   newArray = arr;
```